# Dynamic Ordering in solr result using Sunspot

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I want to implement dynamic ordering in my solr search.

For eg: if i am selecting the country as India, the members from India has to come in top of the result and members from other countries has to come after that.

Anyone knows, how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically boost the results at query time e.g. with India, to a higher value so that they come on top and the rest follow.